# ViewFlipper with loading image from URL in Android

Tags: android

I am totally new to android and I am trying to develop a screen that is similar to flipkart.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there any API's that can help me with this? Or should I develop it from scratch using ViewFlipper?

I have all this image online and can get the links for both Slideshow and product?

It would be great if someone can guide me to right API on this?

Thanks!

Comment: You ca use viewpagerindicator library instead of using viewflipper for above layout

Comment: But will this be useful only for indicator or even for slideshow?

Comment: it will be useful for both

Comment: actually this is a viewpager without tabs